# How to check if a string contains a database record?

Tags: c#, sql, database, string

I have a string (a long file path) and need to check if the string contains a database record. How can I do this?

Simplified Example:

`string filePath = @"C:\Users\me\folder1\foo\bar\documents\photos\img1.jpg";`

My database table is a single column of records:

```
foo
bar
asdf
movies
videos
```

I want to search `filePath` to see if it contains any records in the database (foo, bar, etc), and return those records. In my example, the `filePath` contains `foo` and `bar` so I would return `foo` and `bar`.

I really have thousands of file paths to search and my database is only about 100 database records but will slowly get bigger.

Really lost on where to start on this or if this is even the best way to go about this but I can't think of another way to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: You would just run a `.Contains()` on it- `if (filePath.Contains("foo") && filePath.Contains("bar")) { ... }` . Additionally, have you tried any code yourself to get the results you're wanting? Or are you asking us to write that code for you?

Comment: @Symon I would do `.Contains()` but I need to search my string for hundreds of different smaller strings, not just one or two.

Comment: Then you can pass the string to your database with a stored procedure, and run a check to see if there's any records within the string? [SQL Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) . The procedure could then return either the strings found, or a `1/0` to tell you "yes, it contains `foobar` " or "no, it doesn't contain `foo bar`"

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to split the path string and then do a SELECT query with a WHERE IN, e.g.

```
SELECT SomeColumns
FROM MyTable
WHERE ColumnName IN ('string1', 'string2' ...);
```

But the approach I would take would be to index all of the paths in something like Apache Lucene, and then for each term in the database query the index to see what paths it hits against. That's a pretty trivial use of Lucene and you should be able to easily find tutorials online.

Comment: Lucene sounds interesting! I will definitely check that out

Comment: @kryz Be extremely careful here, it'd be very easy to accidentally leave yourself open to sql injection with a naive implementation of this.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use c# code to do it.

The following is a code example.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionstring = @"";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\me\folder1\foo\bar\documents\photos\img1.jpg";
            var list = ReturnList(connection,filePath);


        }
        static List<string> ReturnList(SqlConnection connection,string path)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            char[] t = { '\\'};
            var array=path.Split(t).ToList();
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "select * from Record";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                string a = reader["Name"].ToString();
                if(array.Contains(a))
                {
                    list.Add(a);
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
            return list;
        }
```

Result:

[image]